# Linux block device IOCTL cmd codes

Tags: linux-device-driver, ioctl

I am developing a Linux block driver and I am currently testing it. I have an IOCTL function which doesnt do anything at the moment. I just use a printk to print the cmd and arg parameters. When Linux starts up it calls the IOCTL function with a cmd of 5331 and arg of 0. I am trying to find out what this cmd could be. The only thing I can find is a reference to a CDROM capability. Does Linux think my device is a CDROM? If so how can I tell it otherwise? thanks

```
static int mydrv_ioctl(struct block_device *bdev, fmode_t mode, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

Comment: I assume the command code 5331 is hexadecimal? In that case it is indeed `CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY`. Maybe something is checking whether the block device is a CDROM or not.

Comment: I am not sure why it would think that it is. I dont know enough about Linux at the moment, to know if you can set some parameter to let Linux know the type of device that the driver is targeting.

Answer (score 0):

I found some example code for a ram block device. They implement an ioctl function and check for the 0x5331 code. They just return an error if the flag GENHD_FL_CD is not set.

```
 case CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY: //0x5331  / * get capabilities * / 
      {
          struct gendisk *disk = bdev->bd_disk;

          if (bdev->bd_disk && (disk->flags & GENHD_FL_CD))
              ret = SUCCESS;
          else
              ret = -EINVAL;
          break;
      }
```